# css transtion not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to move an image from the bottom of the page to the top. I was trying to do it in a way that this transition occurs after a series of events like fadeIn and fadeOuts.

Here is my javascript:

```
//move the circles
$("#fullcircles").delay(1500).fadeIn();                                
//document.getElementById("fullcircles").style.display = "block"; 
$(".circlesfull").toggleClass("move-circle");
```

and the css

```
.circlesfull{
height:100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
display: none;

-webkit-transition: top 2s;
-moz-transition: top 2s;
-o-transition: top 2s;
transition: top 2s;
top: 800px; 
}

/*trigger the moving of the circles*/
.move-circle{
    top:80px;
}
```

This code does not animate the transition. It just instantly moves it.

If i do the same in CSS it animates the transition properly.

```
.content2:hover .circlesfull{
top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a working demo of what you have so far? Have you tried moving the `$.toggleClass()` into a callback of `$.fadeIn()`?